# calculate array values input from first row and first column

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, pandas, vectorization

I would like to calculate matrix values using a separate function and taking the first column and first row as input.

I would like to receive advice on optimising the code below:

```py
#imports
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


#numpy variant

#creation of sample matrix
x_range = range(-180, -80, 20)
y_range = range(5, 30, 5)

ma = np.zeros(shape=(6,6))
ma[0,1:] = x_range
ma[1:,0] = y_range
ma[0,0] = np.nan

# test function:
def test_func(x, y):
    z = (x + y) / 10

    return z  

#looping
for y in range(1, len(ma[0,:])):
    for x in range(1, len(ma[:,0])):
        #print ma[0, x], ma[y, 0]
        ma[x, y] = test_func(ma[0, x], ma[y, 0])

ma
array([[   nan, -180. , -160. , -140. , -120. , -100. ],
       [   5. ,  -17.5,  -17. ,  -16.5,  -16. ,  -15.5],
       [  10. ,  -15.5,  -15. ,  -14.5,  -14. ,  -13.5],
       [  15. ,  -13.5,  -13. ,  -12.5,  -12. ,  -11.5],
       [  20. ,  -11.5,  -11. ,  -10.5,  -10. ,   -9.5],
       [  25. ,   -9.5,   -9. ,   -8.5,   -8. ,   -7.5]])

#pandas variant

cols = x_range
idx = y_range

#dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(np.zeros(shape=(5,5)), index=idx, columns=cols)
df.index.name = 'Y-Range'
df.columns.name = 'X-Range'

df
X-Range  -180  -160  -140  -120  -100
Y-Range                              
5           0     0     0     0     0
10          0     0     0     0     0
15          0     0     0     0     0
20          0     0     0     0     0
25          0     0     0     0     0


#looping
for col in range(0, (len(df.columns))):
    for ind in range(0, (len(df.index))):
        df.iloc[ind, col] = test_func(df.index[ind], df.columns[col])

df
X-Range  -180  -160  -140  -120  -100
Y-Range                              
5         -18   -16   -14   -12   -10
10        -17   -15   -13   -11    -9
15        -17   -15   -13   -11    -9
20        -16   -14   -12   -10    -8
25        -16   -14   -12   -10    -8
#rounding due to console settings
```

This above is exactly what I wanted.

But is there a better way, more efficient and avoiding the loop?

Note:
thanks for the respondes.

Comment: If you have implemented a loopy version that works, add that into the question?

Comment: What is recommended final output?

Comment: Before editing - `ma[1,2] / 10  = -15.5`  after editing `ma[1,2] = -17`. Is it correct?

Answer (score 3):

After setting up `ma`, you can replace the nested loops for a vectorized approach by extending dimensions of one of the sliced portions : `ma[0,1:]` and *add* with another slice `ma[1:,0]`, which will bring in [`broadcasting`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) into play. Being a vectorized approach, this must be pretty fast. Thus, the loop replacement would look like this -

```
ma[1:,1:] = ma[0,1:][:,None] + ma[1:,0]
```

Please note that a more compact way to write `ma[0,1:][:,None]` would be `ma[0,1:,None]`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`add`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.add.html) and [`T`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.transpose.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame(ma)  
print df  

    0    1    2    3    4    5
0 NaN -180 -160 -140 -120 -100
1   5    0    0    0    0    0
2  10    0    0    0    0    0
3  15    0    0    0    0    0
4  20    0    0    0    0    0
5  25    0    0    0    0    0

df.ix[1:,1:] = (df.ix[1:,1:].add(df.ix[1:,0],axis=0) + df.ix[0,1:]).T
print df

    0    1    2    3    4    5
0 NaN -180 -160 -140 -120 -100
1   5 -175 -170 -165 -160 -155
2  10 -155 -150 -145 -140 -135
3  15 -135 -130 -125 -120 -115
4  20 -115 -110 -105 -100  -95
5  25  -95  -90  -85  -80  -75
```